# Measuring Template Performance

Tags: cache, performance, templating

I've got a news website built and I am in the process of improving it's performance. What would be the best way to measure the performance of my templates?

I can use Chrome Developer tools to measure how long it takes for the server to respond but is that the best way of doing it or can I do it internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), you'll get code profiling information (execution times, memory used, stack traces, etc.) that you can use to debug templates with in your browser's console as well as in the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder.

Comment: There's also the old [Profilr plugin](https://github.com/sathoro/Profilr)... how much of that is redundant with the console log output?

Comment: Looks like it's duplicating most of it and just adding a nice UI for it.

Comment: Nice UIs are for suckers. ;)

Comment: Hahaha, yeah... definitely... *looks around before clicking on the download button*